# Complexity of an algorithm with while and for

Tags: time-complexity

I need to calculate the complexity of the following code:

```
function(a)
   n=length(a)
   i=1
   while i<=n
        for j=n to i+1
            print(a)
        i = i+5
```

The while loop is running n/5 times, but I am confused by the for loop.
is it n/5 as well?

any guidance would be appreciated.
thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. If this is your first time posting, it's worth reading through the ["what is on topic"](/help/on-topic) and ["how do I ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask) articles, to make sure your question ends up being the kind the people can answer. In this case, it sounds like you have a homework exercise, so you should probably mention whether it is or not. If you need to calculate the complexity, remember that constant factors are irrelevant: 5n, n, or n/5 all have complexity O(n), so focus on "as `n` increases, how many more operations end up getting run?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the for-loop does properly count downwards (i.e. this isn't a trick question where the for-loop is always empty), then I think the complexity is O(n^2).

If you consider the first pass of the while-loop, the for-loop has about n iterations. The next iteration has about n-5, then n-10, etc., for each of the roughly n/5 iterations of the while-loop. The number of print statements is then the sum of an arithmetic series, with n/5 terms and an average value of about n/2. Thus, overall, one would expect a complexity of O(n^2), or more accurately about n*n/10 passes of the inner for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Generally nested loops are considered as `O(n*m)` where `n` are the number of iterations of the first loop and `m` the number of iterations of the second loop.

Of course, this is over-simplification because is not considering the fact that `n` scales by 5 and `m` starts at `i` and ends on `i+1`.

Surelly in best case scenarios it won't be `O(n*m)` but a general rule of thumb is always look for the worst case scenario and that is `O(n*m)`.

Personal tip, when I try to analyze complexity I guide by the [BigO Cheatsheet](http://bigocheatsheet.com/).